# Find the key in a map whose values satisfy a function

Tags: scala

I am completely new to functional programming and I am working with scala. I am currently writing a program for my university coursework.

I have inputted the following map:

```
    val mapdata = Map(
    "SK1" -> List(9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1),
    "SK2" -> List(0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1),
    "SK3" -> List(8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 6),
    "SK4" -> List(2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 9),
    "SK5" -> List(2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3),
    "SK6" -> List(2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9),
    "SK7" -> List(6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0),
    "SK8" -> List(2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6),
    "SK9" -> List(7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6)
    )
```

I am trying to output the key (stock symbol) which contains the maximum increase.

I have managed to find the maximum increase using the following code:

```
    def mostRecent(Is:List[Int]): Int = {
      if (Is.tail == Nil)
        return Is.head
      else
        mostRecent(Is.tail)
    }

    def penultimate(x: List[Int]): Int = x(x.length - 2)

    //this definition allow me to subtract the mostRecentValues and the penultimate values
    def subtractLast2(pen: Iterable[Int], last: Iterable[Int]): Iterable[Int] = {
         pen zip last map(x => x._1 - x._2)
    }

    //outputs a list with containing the last values 
    val MostRecentPrices = mapdata.values.map(x => mostRecent(x))

    //outputs a list with containing the second last values 
    val penultimatePrices = mapdata.values.map(x => penultimate(x))

    //determines the maximum increase 
    val maxIncrease = (subtractLast2(MostRecentPrices, penultimatePrices)).max


    //output the stock that has increased the most in the last day of the period
    println("MaxIncrease = " + maxIncrease)
```

I thought I was just about there until I found out I had to output the key that corresponds with the calculated maximum increase.

Was thinking of using getOrElse but really not sure as I am a beginner in scala and functional programming.

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, we've seen a lot of the SKn data recently. Good to know it's a course. I could provide code, but it would be better if you studied the API doc a bit (for instance, your `mostRecent(x)` is `x.last`, and `penultimate` is `x.init.last`). Also, is the definition of your required increase really just the increase in the last day? If,  instead, it was the biggest increase in any day, you should look into `sliding`. One more `pen zip last map(x => x._1 - x._2)` is just `last - pen`, (well, wrapped in a `Iterable`), not sure why you're going around the houses there.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate two last elements by using pattern matching:

```scala
def mostRecent(is: List[Int]): (Int, Int) =
  is match {
    case a +: b +: Nil => (a, b)
    case head +: tail => mostRecent(tail)
    case Nil => throw new Exception("Can't calculate for an empty list")
  }
```

First it matches on `a +: b +: Nil` which extracts two first elements if tail is the end of the list. If it can't match this case, it tries to decompose the list as head +: tail, so it can call itself recursively for the tail. In case it was called with an empty list first it throws an exception.

Then, for every entry in `mapdata` you can calculate the two most recent elements, and subtract them:

```scala
val increases = 
  for {
    (k, v) <- mapdata
    (a, b) = mostRecent(v)
  } yield (k, b - a)
```

As a last step you can find maximum using `maxBy` method:

```scala
val max = increases.maxBy(_._2) 
max: (String, Int) = ("SK4", 7)
```